# Access files on Amazon S3 using HTML5 / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, amazon-s3

Is it possible to access the files on Amazon S3 using JavaScript / HTML5. I basically plan to access these files in a PhoneGap app.

To be more specific, I mean without any server in middle i.e. making direct calls to Amazon S3. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question - I came up with a JavaScript S3 request signer using which I was able to sign the URL and access the files on S3 from JavaScript.

Anybody needs any details, please leave comment and would be happy to assist.

Cheers

Comment: I'd love to know more, I don't want to whitelist all of s3 in my phonegap app, and have been considering simply proxying all the requests instead.

Comment: I've a JS file which I use to sign the GET request for fetching the files from S3. Let me know if you need to know anything specific.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  You can enable CORS for your bucket so that objects can be loaded via `XMLHttpRequest`.

- http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

When using PhoneGap/Cordova specifically, you may be able to bypass enabling CORS on the server by whitelisting the domain from within your app:

- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for the links. I believe there would be security concerns by enabling cross-origin requests, isn't?

Comment: I updated the question with more specific details.. I don't have (plan to ) have any server in middle of app and amazon

Comment: Can you be more specific about security concerns?  http://annevankesteren.nl/2012/12/cors-101

Comment: Sorry, I acknowledge that cross-domain policy issues don't become an obstacle in phonegap apps, so we can skip the whole point of enabling CORS on Amazon S3. My main question is - Can I interact with Amazon S3 to View / Download files using Plain JavaScript?